# Setup FTP (vsftpd is not running)

Tags: ftp

--UPDATE--

I've noticed that my problem is because for some reason vsftpd does not run.  Even when I tell it to run via "service vsftpd start".  It says the process is running on some PID, but when I check that PID nothing is running.

--UPDATE--

I'm trying to add FTP to my server.  I would like *only* authenticated users to have ftp access.  I also want to allow updating of files and not read only access.  However for some reason things are not working.  Please note, I will be adding the user "user_foobar".  This is what I've done so far:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
sudo usermod -d /the/folder/that/ftp/should user_foobar
```

I've then updated the /etc/vsftpd.conf file with the following info:

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

Lastly I then edited the file /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list to have the line:

```
user_foobar
```

However when I restart the service "service vsftpd restart" I get the following output:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
vsftpd start/pre-start, process 8478
```

Also when I try and view the ftp site in Chrome by the following url,

```
ftp://myftpsite
```

Nothing is shown.

Comment: I would recommend remove (purging) your vsftp install and then reinstalling it with default conf files and starting the service and confirming it is running. I think you have a bad conf file that is causing it not to run properly.

Comment: @kingmilo.  That indeed sorted the problem out.  I just had a bad conf file.  Sigh... I had been pulling my hair out for a few hours trying to spot that.

Comment: Glad it's sorted, been down that road many times :)

Comment: Son of a bitch, i have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend remove (purging) your vsftp install and then reinstalling it with default conf files and starting the service and confirming it is running. I think you have a bad conf file that is causing it not to run properly.