# vsftpd NOT STARTING BUG- apt-get-purge error

Tags: services, ftp, vsftpd

i successfully installed, configured, and used vsftpd.  But after restart something became corrupted, now

```
:~# service vsftpd status
:~# service vsftpd start
:~# service vsftpd restart
:~# service vsftpd stop
:~# netstat -an | grep :21
```

(all return no error, and no info message)

`:~# chkconfig --list | grep ftp`

RETURNS:

`atftpd                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off`
`vsftpd                    0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off`

/var/log/vsftpd.log.1 - contains:

```
Fri Jul 18 12:15:14 2014 [pid 2] CONNECT: Client "192.168.0.2"
Fri Jul 18 12:15:14 2014 [pid 1] [ftp] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.0.2", anon password "mozilla@example.com"
```

/var/log/vsftpd.log is empty

dmseg log has no entry containing vsftpd

...here is my etc/vsftpd.conf file:

```
#standalone
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=no
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

[Setup FTP (vsftpd is not running)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358963/setup-ftp-vsftpd-is-not-running)
 - reccomends purging vsftpd....but there i have another problem......

[This is the same problem i am having purging vsftp](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/474137/remove-vsftpd-on-kali-linux)

`:~# apt-get purge vsftpd`

produces the error:

```
Removing vsftpd ...
update-inetd: --disable requires only one argument
dpkg: error processing vsftpd (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vsftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

1. Is the only work-around for the vsftp "not-starting bug" a complete purge and reinstall/reconfigure?
2. What is the simplest work-around for the common vsftp purge completion problem?
3. does anyone care to share another more reliable ftp program/daemon that is easy to configure and safe like vsftp?  but lacking the functional bugs vsftp has...  proftp?

Comment: this same set of problems can be recreated on both ubuntu desktop and debian based kali

Comment: i can not post the purge solution url in my answer so ...Removing proftpd (http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/universe/p/proftpd-basic/uninstall.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vsftpd is known to not start after its initial use (see links in question) - if your one of those affected then there is no known cure.....

BUT proftpd is a popular alternative that does seem to be more universally dependable.  Here are the steps to get proftpd and its guiadmin up and running

> :#apt-get install proftpd

-answer ok to "stand alone"

> :#apt-get install gadmin-proftpd

-go to Applications ->SystemTools->GADMIN

> :#rm /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

to remove .conf file if you don't then an alert will popup saying proftpd.conf was renamed and moved to gadmin/folder

Do you want to overwrite your current proftpd configuration
with a suitable standard configuration for gadmin-proftpd ? (SELECT Yes)

mount directory you will use for ftp upload/download

> :#mkdir /media/wob
>
> :#mount /dev/sda4 /media/wob

In admin program

-Server tab

```
-signed certificate settings:

-fill in password

-click apply button or ftp will not work!
```

-Users tab

```
-click +New user button

-click +Add directory button (media/wob)

    -enable upload and just about all directory settings

-Click Apply button next to +New user button
```

-Click Activate at top of admin program to start ftp

Useful site and reference sites:

GADMIN-PROFTPD start up error fix (http://linuxhackrzz.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-get-rid-of-errors-in-gadmin.html)

Proftpd admin mangager (http://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/installing-and-configuring-proftpd/)

Answer (score 1):

If you find error in  purging the package VSFTPD , then you can manually delete it by following the below steps :

Change to this dir

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Search for the residue files ,here its vsftpd

```
ls | grep vsftpd
```

To remove vsftpd files

```
ls | grep vsftpd | xargs rm -i -f '{}'
```

Second location

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/  
rm <vsftpd releated deb files >
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Now start installing your favorite FTP package.